# how to change datafrmae name dynamically

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a problem while naming dataframes in pandas. Is there any way to automate the naming and index changing instead of writing it line by line manually?

```
xl=pd.ExcelFile('Movement of BSE RIK.xlsx',header=0,dtype={'Open Price 

(Rs.)':np.float64})

p=xl.sheet_names

df= xl.parse('D-0')

df1= xl.parse('D-1')

df2= xl.parse('D-2')

df3= xl.parse('D-3')

df4= xl.parse('D-4')

df5= xl.parse('D-5')

df6= xl.parse('D-6')

df7= xl.parse('D-7')

df8= xl.parse('D-8')


df9= xl.parse('D-9')

df10= xl.parse('D-10')

df11= xl.parse('D-11')

df12= xl.parse('D-12')

df13= xl.parse('D-13')

df14= xl.parse('D-14')

df.set_index('Security Name',inplace=True)
df1.set_index('Security Name',inplace=True)
df2.set_index('Security Name',inplace=True)
df3.set_index('Security Name',inplace=True)
df4.set_index('Security Name',inplace=True)
df5.set_index('Security Name',inplace=True)
df6.set_index('Security Name',inplace=True)
df7.set_index('Security Name',inplace=True)
df8.set_index('Security Name',inplace=True)
df9.set_index('Security Name',inplace=True)
df10.set_index('Security Name',inplace=True)
df11.set_index('Security Name',inplace=True)
df12.set_index('Security Name',inplace=True)
df13.set_index('Security Name',inplace=True)
df14.set_index('Security Name',inplace=True)
```

this code is very lengthy and I have to work further using those dataframe names.in short, I want to minimize the lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use parameter [`sheetname=None`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#specifying-sheets) for creating `dict` of `DataFrames`:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('Movement of BSE RIK.xlsx',
                   header=0,
                   dtype={'Open Price (Rs.)':np.float64}, 
                   sheetname=None,
                   index_col='Security Name')
```

and then you can select `DataFrames` by:

```
print (dfs['D-0'])

print (type(dfs['D-0']))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Sample with [file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/84444599/Movement%20of%20BSE%20RIK.xlsx):

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('Movement of BSE RIK.xlsx',
                   header=0,
                   dtype={'Open Price (Rs.)':np.float64}, 
                   sheetname=None,
                   index_col='Security Name')
print (dfs)

print (dfs['D-0'])

               a  b  Open Price (Rs.)
Security Name                        
1              r  u               3.0
4              t  j               5.0
```

Comment: I see your question and I want help you. First add `thousands=','` parameter `dfs = pd.read_excel('Movement of BSE RIK.xlsx',header=0,dtype={'Open Price (Rs.)':np.float64,'Close Price (Rs.)':np.float64}, sheetname=None, thousands=',')` and then use `dfs['D-0'].plot.bar(y='Open Price (Rs.)', x='Security Name')`. But there is a lot of data.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a dictionary of DataFrames:

```
dfs = {n:xl.parse(n).set_index('Security Name') for n in xl.sheet_names}
```